# Is there anyway to get a value from app script and update the sheet in realtime instead of calculated field?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two spread sheet files.

`A file` is for showing result for customers. You can select type and amount. So, it shows the total price and
time.

`B file`: data file. It must be invisible for customers. This file contains some data about price by values. And the price calculation part is not simple, So, I think it needs app script.

But, What I want to implement is, auto update the field like what calculated fields do. It should update the result fields right away and automatically.

My first question is 'is there anyway to call API?' because app script needs to be called to get the return value.

My second question is 'is it possible to update the result fields right away, and automatically?' because as far as I know there's no way to detect the completion event.

Comment: I believe you can use an [`onEdit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) so that when you edit the `B file`, the `A file` value gets re-computed. Could you provide a minimal example of the Sheets so that we may provide a tailored response? Cheers

Comment: I solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59626205/how-to-request-or-get-the-permission-of-google-spread-sheet-access-in-the-apps-s

Comment: Thanks a lot @c-an. Kindly provide a brief answer explaining how you did that so other users of the platform may benefit of this question. Cheers!