# How to request or get the permission of google spread sheet access in the apps script of other sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing apps script of A spread sheet for my custom functions and trying to get values in B spread sheet from there using `openUrl()`

However, I got `ERROR` in A spreadsheet when I use the custom function..

in Google Document, it says

> If your custom function throws the error message You do not have permission to call X service., the service requires user authorization and thus cannot be used in a custom function.

ref: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

However, it doesn't say anything how to get the permission..

1. I tried with sharable link to everyone but it didn't work.
2. I tried with `url&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`

Both way didn't work. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're asking for cannot be done directly. In the same documentation, please scroll all the way down to sharing; that's -

Custom Functions in Google Sheets > Advanced > [Sharing](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#sharing).

Here, you'll see the following -

> Custom functions start out [bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) to the spreadsheet they were created in. This means that a **custom function written in one spreadsheet can't be used in other spreadsheets** unless...

If it suits you, you can make use of the 3 methods that they've listed there to overcome this problem.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved:

You can't access other spreadsheet files, which means you can't use `openById()` or `openByUrl()`. So, there is only one method you can achieve this - using `getActiveSpreadSheet()` which is the current spreadsheet that the app script belongs to.

If you wanted to hide the original file, then you can consider making a reference file that is sharable for anyone. And your original file is private.

So, You need to make it one more file to share.

1. original file (private)

Use `getactiveSpreadSheet()` instead of `openById()` or `openByUrl()`. And implement your custom functions. You won't have any problem with accessing the current spreadsheet in this way.

```
function YOUR_CUSTOM_FUNCTION(val1, val2, ...){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("YOUR_SHEET_NAME");

    return getMyValue(val1, val2, ...);
}

function getMyValue(val1, val2, ...){
    var result = 0;

    // TODO: calculate values as you want.

    return result;
}
```

Use your custom function in the file like this:

```
=YOUR_CUSTOM_FUNCTION(E5, F6, ...)
```

You won't get any ERROR.

2. reference file (sharable)

You can make a reference sheet with using:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("spread sheet link","sheet_name!range")
```

This will show access button to get authorization. Once you click, it will make a reference from your original sheet.

*range is something like `A:C` or `A1:Z55`.